# Is it safe to run a Mac Mini (i5) on its side?

Tags: mac-mini

I recently got a Mac Mini with the i5 chip. Is it OK to set it on its side and run it that way? I wanted to shrink the footprint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure.  Just make sure it is in a secure position so it doesn't fall over.

Apple actually has a support page on this:  http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22804

Comment: Keep in mind that the aluminum case can dissipate a huge amount of the internal heat, so you can generally keep the fans running lower RPM by maintaining good airflow even while it is vertically positioned. The mac will shut off if it overhears, so this is more of a noise and slightly faster heat relating aging of the components issue.

Answer (score -2):

No it's not. It will heat up fast.